# Perl - threads join and system running out of memory

Tags: arrays, multithreading, perl

I posted [couple of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348367/array-missing-elements-with-a-subroutine-thread) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326515/perl-create-a-new-array-and-pass-it-to-a-subroutine-thread) for array and threads in my Perl code. Here is the code again. 
Based on the suggestions, I made changes and it seemed to be working. Still the code is running into a new issue. The machine is running out of memory. Many threads are finished and unjoined.

**Code** -

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w -I /opt/hypertable/0.9.7.3/lib/perl -I /opt/hypertable/0.9.7.3/lib/perl/gen-perl
use strict;
use IO::Socket;
use Geo::IP;
use threads qw(stringify);
use Net::NBName;
use Data::Dumper;
use Hypertable::ThriftClient;

# Syslog Variables and Constants
my $MAXLEN = 1524;
my $limit = 5; #for testing
my $sock;
my $thr;
# Start Listening on UDP port 514
$sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(LocalPort => '514', Proto => 'udp') || die("Socket: $@");

my $buf = '';
do{
my $count = 0;
my @set;

for ($count = 0; $count <= $limit; $count++) {
  $sock->recv($buf, $MAXLEN);
  my ($port, $ipaddr) = sockaddr_in($sock->peername);
  my $hn = gethostbyaddr($ipaddr, AF_INET);
  $buf =~ /<(\d+)>(.*?):(.*)/;
  my $msg = $3;
  $set[$count][0] = $hn;
  $set[$count][3] = $msg;
  print $count." --> ".$set[$count][0]." --> ".$set[$count][4]."\n";#Print original array, should print 5 elements 

  $thr = threads->create('logsys',@set);

  #&logsys(@set);
}
}while(1);

$thr->join();

sub logsys {
  my $count = 0;
  my @set = @_;
  my $geoip = Geo::IP->new(GEOIP_CHECK_CACHE);
  my $nb = Net::NBName->new;

  print "--------------------- ".scalar (@set)." -------------------\n";

  for ($count=0; $count <= $limit; $count++) {
    print $count." --> ".$set[$count][0]." --> ".$set[$count][5]."\n";#print passed array, should same exact 5 elements
    if (open(WW,">syslog")){
      print WW $count." --> ".$set[$count][0]." --> ".$set[$count][6]."\n"; close(WW);
    }
  }
}
```

**Error -**

```
Out of memory!
Callback called exit at /usr/lib/perl/5.10/IO/Socket.pm line 287.
Thread 646 terminated abnormally: main=HASH(0xee3b3068) at ./syslogd.pl line 50.
Perl exited with active threads:
        9 running and unjoined
        644 finished and unjoined
        0 running and detached
```

What does this mean? Why the machine is running out of memory even when many threads are finished? How do I fix this? I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: why aren't you closing the filehandles? also, use lexical file handles. detach or join your threads, depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `join` or `detach` the threads to free up the memory they are retaining.

Just add :

```
$thr->detach();
```

after the thread creation, or make a dedicated thread to join the other threads once they are finished, if you need to retreive their result somehow.

Seeing your update of the code, you seem to want to join the created threads, but you try to do so outside the `do` loop, which does not seem to end. The `join` call is therefore never reached apparently. Even if it did, the `$thr` variable would only contain a reference to the latest created thread, and hence would only allow to join that very instance.

Given what I see of your code, I think the best course of action is really to have your threads run in detached state, and have them push to a queue whatever result they need to return.

Comment: Please have a look at the code again, I missed some part of it, edited my question to add proper code. I run a do while loop endlessly and doing thr->join(); Still getting the error of running out of memory.

Comment: So I should do `$thr = threads->create('logsys',@set,$hypertable); $thr->detach();` in the do-while loop. This will create a thread and detach it, once the thread is over then the memory will be freed automatically.

Comment: that's what the thread doxumentation says. You should however properly close all the file handles and release the allocated resources used by the thread if you can as soon as possible, in order to have as much free memory as possible at any time during the threads execution.

Comment: Thanks, I made that change, it's looking better now. Is there is way to display the status' of all threads created?

Comment: use `threads->list()` to get the list of existing threads, and `is_running`, `is_joinable`, `is_detached` methods on each of them to know their states.